# Detect changes in Wifi

Tags: c#, wifi, xamarin.forms

I need to detect when wifi is turned on/off. For that purpose I'm using Connectivity by James Montemagno, but the problem is that I don't get an ConnectivityChanged event  if the Phone have access to mobile network and I turn on/off the  wifi.

Here is the mapping of the event:

```
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        WiFiConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectionTypes.Contains(ConnectionType.WiFi);
    };
```

So can I detect Connectivity Changed on Wifi? I would like to do it in Xamarin Forms code so I won't have to implement a solution for each platform.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ?

Comment: I have tried "ConnectivityTypeChanged" instead of "ConnectivityChanged". But the issue I am facing is "ConnectivityTypeChanged" event is getting triggered multiple times on changing Wifi/Cellular. I just need to trigger only one notification like "ConnectivityChanged" .CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityTypeChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        WiFiConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectionTypes.Contains(ConnectionType.WiFi);
    };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here What Your Looking For

```
     CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {

                if (args.IsConnected.ToString().Equals("False"))
                {
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectionTypes.Contains(ConnectionType.WiFi))
                    {
                        // WE LOST AN CONNECTION BUT WIFI IS STILL ON 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectionTypes.Contains(ConnectionType.WiFi))
                    {
                        // WIFI WAS TURN ON AND WE HAVE A CONNECTION 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // WE HAVE A CONNECTION BUT NOT WIFI
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: The link to plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin

Comment: "ConnectivityChanged" only checks if internet connection is available or not, so in the above case when the Wifi is disconnected, still the mobile internet will be available and this method won't get called. How to handle this case ?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if there is a xamarin forms solution but you can do it plateform specific. In android with BroadcastReceiver.. for other plateforms i have no idea..

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you.